# Ubuntu 17.10 RTL8723BU

Tags: wireless, 17.10, realtek

I have a [USB wireless dongle](https://www.amazon.fr/iFun4U-adapteur-Bluetooth-vitesse-Compatible/dp/B01JS0CLR2). It doesn't work out of the box on Ubuntu but works fine with [this GitHub driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu) on Ubuntu 16.04. With a fresh install of 17.10, I have the same problem, & the driver from GitHub doesn't help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What was the output of `sudo modprobe -v 8723bu`.

Answer (score 2):

Had problems (terrible wifi connectivity) with an internal wifi card (same chipset: rtl8723bu) on a Medion Akoya laptop (Akoya S4219-MD60740, ubuntu 16.04). Installing the github driver helps only after blacklisting rtl8xxxu. Now works like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

OK it works now

I had to compil driver and add

> blacklist rtl8xxxu

in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf